# SE for teachers/school

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

My girlfriend works as a school teacher, and as she takes a long time in correcting compositions I want to ask a question about homeworks correction. Is there any appropriate network/site here on Stack Exchange?

Comment: Area51 has a site in definition, but I'm not aware of any active teacher-oriented stacks. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33114/education-technology

Comment: Is it a question specific to any academic subject or just about the process in general?

Comment: @jonsca  not really to any subject. Just the ones who require the pupil to make a composition in their native language.

Comment: Well, there is a writing site, but you'd have to check their faq as to whether techniques for critiquing would be on topic there.

Answer (score 4):

[Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com) might consider this on-topic, depending on how the question is formatted:

- If it's about redlining a student essay and the issues involved with doing that, it's essentially an editing question, which would be on-topic. If it's about presenting constructive criticism and encouraging good writing habits, that would also be on-topic.
- If it's about grading, or student interaction, or setting up assignments, that would be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Also, feel free to ask about this on our Meta site if you're not sure of how to format the question.

Comment: Neil, thanks. You refer to writer meta, isn't it? I also submitted it to personal productioviti on SE http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/how-to-spend-less-time-in-compositions-correction it seems it is a good place. Do you think submitting it also to writers, with a different format, is a good idea?

Comment: By the way, as I surprisingly noticed that no networks for undergraduate teachers where availabe on SE, I just proposed one http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49571/teachers-school

Comment: @DanieleB - "Do you think submitting it also to writers, with a different format, is a good idea?" - Only if there are aspects of the question that the existing question you posted isn't covering that you think Writers can cover well. Also, yes, I meant Writers meta.

Answer (score 0):

The only suitable place I found to make this question was the [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/)  site, where I asked this: [How to spend less time in compositions correction?](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/how-to-spend-less-time-in-compositions-correction) which seems to get some answers.

In any case as I saw there was no ntwork for undergraduate schools, I opened this site proposal: [**Undergraduates**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49571/undergraduates)